# Internet Constantly Disconnects (Skype works, browers do not)

Tags: internet, skype, cable

My internet connection seems very unstable. I'm on cable, and for my internet just keeps going down for no reason.

Sometimes:

1. Everything goes down
2. Browers just stop working but skype works

> I read online somewhere, for situation 2 that I could just do this in cmd:
>   ipconfig /flushdns
>   ipconfig /release
>   ipconfig /renew

How do I fix these problems?

If you know of way, please explain step-by-step.

Comment: try a different browser, or which ones have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using internet via Proxy or through a direct connection, As skype detects proxy automatically and browsers does not do that in most cases. Try setting up proxy in browser and try browsing if you are using proxy.

Comment: Now my Wifi isn't working, but everything else is. I'm using internet through direct connection.